# how do i return a modified value into an array

Tags: javascript

I am working on problem and hoping someone could point me in the right direction. the problem is to find the longest word in a sentence and then return that sentence with the longest word capitalized. So far I have been able to find the longest word in a sentence and capitalize it BUT I am not able to return the sentence with the capitalized word as a part of it.

```js
    var capitalize = document.getElementById('capitalize');
    var myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
    var myInput;
    
    capitalize.addEventListener('click',function(){
     myInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
    
     mySplitInput = myInput.split(' ');
     
     var longest='';
     for(var i = 0 ; i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
      if( mySplitInput[i].length > longest.length){
       longest = mySplitInput[i].toUpperCase();
    
      }
     };
     
     var content = document.createTextNode(longest);
     myOutput.appendChild(content);
    
    });
```

```html
    
      <input type="input" id="input">
     <button id="capitalize">capitalize</button>
     <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the index of the longest word as well as the word itself. Then you can just overwrite the word with that index with its capitalized version and glue the split sentence back together with spaces.

```js
var capitalize = document.getElementById('capitalize');
var myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
var myInput;

capitalize.addEventListener('click',function(){
  myInput = document.getElementById('input').value;

  mySplitInput = myInput.split(' ');

  var longestIndex,
      longest='';
  for(var i = 0 ; i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
    if( mySplitInput[i].length > longest.length){
      longestIndex = i;
      longest = mySplitInput[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  };
  
  mySplitInput[longestIndex] = mySplitInput[longestIndex].toUpperCase();

  var content = document.createTextNode(mySplitInput.join(' '));
  myOutput.appendChild(content);

});
```

```html
<input type="input" id="input">
<button id="capitalize">capitalize</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, just how did you come up with the solution. I'm sure you are more experienced, so it may have just come to you. But as a novice programmer, I was trying to wrap my head around the logic and could not figure this out. Am I just not cut out for this?

Comment: It really was somewhat straight-forward, but of course that is something that will come to you with time and experience. Everyone was a beginner once who struggled with what today seems like very basic stuff. In this case, I suppose you just didn't think that you could alter the array element directly and put the sentence back together?

Comment: I will be reviewing all answers and studying up. Thank you all so much. I think my problem was not so much the logic. I mean I could write out the answer in plain english. I just couldn't find a way to express my answer through code. It seems so simple now looking at it. I'm just frustrated that I was not able to get it because you are right it is rather simple. But again THANK YOU. i really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the existing longest value in a variable and replace that with the capitalized longest value.

```js
var capitalize = document.getElementById('capitalize');
    var myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
    var myInput;
    
    capitalize.addEventListener('click',function(){
     myInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
    
     mySplitInput = myInput.split(' ');
     
     var longest='';
      var existing ='';
     for(var i = 0 ; i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
      if( mySplitInput[i].length > longest.length){
       longest = mySplitInput[i].toUpperCase();
          existing= mySplitInput[i];
      }
     };
     
     var content = document.createTextNode(myInput.replace(existing,longest));
     myOutput.appendChild(content);
    
    });
```

```html
<input type="input" id="input">
     <button id="capitalize">capitalize</button>
     <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution!

```
var capitalize = document.getElementById('capitalize');
var myOutput = document.getElementById('output');
var myInput;

capitalize.addEventListener('click',function(){
    myInput = document.getElementById('input').value;

    mySplitInput = myInput.split(' ');

    var longest='';
    var newString= '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
        if( mySplitInput[i].length > longest.length){
            longest = mySplitInput[i].toUpperCase();
            if(myInput.includes(mySplitInput[i])){
               newString = myInput.replace(mySplitInput[i], longest);
        }
    };

    var content = document.createTextNode(newString);
    myOutput.appendChild(content);

});
```

You can cut out some variables and some checks here but it entirely depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var longest=''; var index =0;
for(var i = 0 ; i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
if( mySplitInput[i].length > longest.length){
 longest = mySplitInput[i].toUpperCase();
 index = i;
 } 
};

var sentence =longest;
for(i=index-1;i >=0; i--){
 if(mySplitInput[i] === '.')
  break;
 sentence=mySplitInput[i] + " "+sentence;
}
for(i=index+1;i < mySplitInput.length; i++){
 if(mySplitInput[i] === '.')
  break;
 sentence+=" "+mySplitInput[i];
}
sentence += '.';
```

I have added an `index` variable to keep track of the index of the `longest` word and then I recreat the the sentence using `for` loops which are designed to traverse forwards and backwards from the index of the longest word until it finds a **'.'(period)**